# Getting an error when I don't run app with the green play button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, adapter

My problem is that my app crashes when I don't run it with the green play button in android studio, and the next problem is that I am getting no line displayed where the error is caused.

Here is the logchat:

```
   `08-17 11:34:03.312 6339-6339/com.test.test.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.test.test, PID: 6339
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.getSnapshot(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:70)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
    at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:83)
    at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:125)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1858)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1191)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:876)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:895)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1171)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)08-17 11:34:03.313 6339-6339/com.test.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:730)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17689)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6343)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)`    

    And here is a sniped of my code:    

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, 
    RecyclerItemTouchHelper.RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager;
    public NoteListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Note> notesList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static NoteViewHolder ch;
    private ListenerRegistration firestoreListener;
    private RecyclerItemTouchHelper.RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvNoteList);

        recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        view_design = 0;
        //SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
        //helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, MainActivity.this);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        makeAdapter();

        firestoreListener = db.collection("users").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("notes")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.e("LOL", "Listen failed!", e);
                            return;
                        }

                        for (DocumentSnapshot doc : documentSnapshots) {
                            Note note = doc.toObject(Note.class);
                            note.setId(doc.getId());
                            notesList.add(note);
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void makeAdapter() {

        Query query = db.collection("users").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("notes");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
                .setQuery(query, Note.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new NoteListAdapter(notesList, response, MainActivity.this);


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        setAlarms();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }}`
```

So because of the error, I think there is anything wrong with the `ArrayList`.  But I can't figure it out what's wrong because when I launch the app about the green play button everything works. Sorry but I never had a problem like this before.
I hope anybody has a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the error cause by getting a empty list with index = 0, can you provide a full log?

Comment: It seems a bit odd that the behavior is different when launched from Android Studio or from the launcher. Are you sure you are opening the same app? You could try to uninstall the app on your device, install it again through the green button, and then retry

Comment: @GianhTran I edited my post. hope it helps.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the ArrayList, you try to get an element from an empty ArrayList. this happens here in your code: BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:70

Comment: @Henry But line 70 is empty.

Comment: Then you most likely changed the code since the stack trace was generated.

Comment: @Henry No sorry. I get the error still now and there is nothing in line 70

Comment: @GianhTran How I can find out the line with Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) remove `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` from `onCreate()`, at this point `adapter` is `null`, later on you call `makeAdapter();` and it will set the adapter.  
2) you don't need `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` if your next statement is         `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` because a new adapter will be set anyway

Comment: Thanks, but have you a solution for my Problem?

Comment: Did you make the above changes?

Comment: Or how I could find out the line with the Error?

Comment: Yes, I did all changes. When I start the app everything works. But now I have the Problem that App crashes when I resume [onResume()] the App.

Comment: This is not relevant with the original question (what happened to the code?). Post another question and supply all the needed code and the logcat for this error.